# Upgrade to Genuine Windows 8 Pro from non genuine Windows 7

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-upgrade

I have a computer with non-genuine windows 7 (cracked with windows loader). I was thinking of buying / upgrading to Windows 8 Pro. I ran `Windows8-UpgradeAssistant.exe` and was said that I can upgrade to Windows 8 Pro.

1. Can I perform a clean upgrade (format and install) from my current windows 7 to windows 8?
2. In future, in order to re-install Windows 8 do I need to re-install the non-genuine Windows 7 and install on top of it?
3. If my hard disk crash, or I want to install on a new hard disk (clean install), do I need to install windows 7 again before upgrading to Windows 8?
4. If I don't like Windows 8, can I downgrade to Windows 7 genuine?

Comment: Without a **legit** licence, you're not permitted to upgrade to Windows 8.

Comment: You should consider a free operating system instead of non-genuiue Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1) Can I perform a clean upgrade (format and install) from my current windows 7 to windows 8?

- **Yes.** Select "Nothing" when the upgrade assistant asks you to
  choose what to keep.

> 2) In future, in order to re-install Windows 8 do I need to re-install the non-genuine Windows 7 and install on top of it?

- **No.** When you purchase Windows 8, the upgrade assistant will let you
  download the ISO file which contains the Windows 8 installer. You can then
  burn the ISO file to a DVD or create a bootable USB flash drive to install Windows 8.

> 3) If my hard disk crash, or I want to install on a new hard disk (clean install), do I need to install windows 7 again before upgrading to Windows 8?

- **No.** Check number 2.

> 4) If I don't like Windows 8, can I downgrade to Windows 7 genuine?

- **No.** You can downgrade to Windows 7 but it won't be **genuine** until you purchase it.

Comment: Why are we talking about illegal software, the author should **purchase** Windows 7, if he doesn't like Windows 8.

Comment: Regarding #2, we have already been discussing this in several threads. So far, the consensus seems to be (bolstered by the advice of MS MVPs on TechNet) that for Win8 Upgrade to activate, the installer requires the older OS to be installed. You can go ahead and format, but the installer must be checking for the presence of the OS and maybe even the license in some way. Otherwise, what would be the difference between the far cheaper upgrade and the costlier System Builder version? If you can absolutely *confirm* otherwise without resorting to mere conjecture, do let us know.

Comment: I did this myself. It works. Check these links : http://techpp.com/2012/10/27/windows-8-promo-code/ http://techpp.com/2012/10/26/upgrade-to-windows-8-from-illegal-windows-7/ They clearly state Microsoft is trying its best to promote Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

If you buy the regular version of Windows 8 Pro (not the upgrade version) then it will solve most of the questions you asked.

1. Only with the regular Windows 8 Pro.
2. If you get the upgrade version then yes you will need to reinstall Windows 7. Buying the regular Windows 8 Pro relieves you of this.
3. Basically number 2.

Comment: No 2 is wrong. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this but as you don't have a valid Windows XP/Vista/7 licence your Windows 8 will still not be legit.

Comment: While what he is doing is wrong, his Windows 8 will be legit, provided he doesn't crack Windows 8 also.

Comment: It will activate, yes, but it doesn't fulfill the licensing terms that enabled him to upgrade in the first place.