# Upgrade illegal windows 7 32bit to genuine windows 8 64

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, 64-bit, 32-bit, windows-8-upgrade

I've seen this post:
[Upgrade to Genuine Windows 8 Pro from non genuine Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/495275/upgrade-to-genuine-windows-8-pro-from-non-genuine-windows-7)

But I need something extra. I need to go from 32bit to 64bit. Is that even possible?

My laptop's upgraded to 64bit. Can I use its ISO and just buy a product key on its own? And do a clean install?

Comment: Even if you can trick the upgrade into thinking something else, your Windows 8 will not be genuine. The only way of obtaining a genuine Windows 8 without having a genuine Windows XP/Vista/7 is to buy the system builder. The alternatives are free operating systems and piracy. Super User won't help you with the latter...

Comment: The Windows 7 upgrade disks only required that your current operating system was licensed. They did not require that the Windows 7 installation would be an actual upgrade and from the DVD you could tell it to do a clean installation. This generally requires booting from the DVD though. This allowed users to upgrade from 32bit to 64bit.

Comment: Dennis, not looking into getting a pirated copy.

NtscCobalt, does booting from a DVD still mean It's an upgrade? What happens if I need to format for some reason? (this is applicable to my genuine laptop I guess)

Comment: @MatthewGrima, Yes I believe so though the process might have changed with windows 8. From what I remember the Windows 7 DVD (when booted from) would check for a valid Windows installation. This still may not work due to an invalid Windows 7 license on your machine. You are given the option to modify partitions before beginning the actual installation.

Comment: @MatthewGrima - Use a 64-it Windows 8 system builder license. Since there is no way to upgrade a 32-bit operating system to a 64-bit operating system without installing the new operating system OVER the existing operating system and losing the system settings and user files that is your only solution.  You will be unable to use a 64-bit Windows 8 Upgrade license.

Comment: Why downvoted and closed? I am not asking anyone to tell me how to rip the new windows. Just want to know what I can do to get(BUY) a genuine. Didn't even know the retail version existed as microsoft only points to upgrades.

Comment: Buy a new version and install that over your pirated version. Don't even pirate in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot upgrade directly from a 32-bit install to a 64-bit one. You will need to do a wipe + fresh install of Windows 8 x64.

As for the licensing aspect, that's generally off-topic for SU, but whether you used a bootleg Windows 7 in the past has no effect on whether you'll be able to install Windows 8 (as long as you have a legit retail key).

Comment: I know that, but my windows 7 is not genuine, can I use the ISO from the other PC and just buy a product key?

Comment: You can use any valid install disc that you want. Are you aiming for an upgrade install, or are you buying a full version of Windows 8?

Comment: Upgrade install would limit me to windows 32 wouldn't it?

It doesn't matter what I do to be honest. All I want is a genuine windows 8 64 bit pc

Comment: @Bigbio2002, you can upgrade using custom install according to http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/32-bit-and-64-bit-Windows-frequently-asked-questions. This will wipe out your data but it will allow you to use an upgrade disk and upgrade key to go from 32bit to 64bit provided you already have a licensed 32bit install.

Comment: @MatthewGrima - No.  You can upgrade to 64-bit but it means doing a clean install, since your current Windows 7 license is not legit, you won't be able to upgrade no matter what.

Answer (score 3):

Buy the OEM version of Windows 8 from a retailer, back up your whole system, do a fresh install of Windows 8, then copy the files you want from your backup.

See: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/windows-8-retail-box-version/7fbc820e-a0a4-4080-b04d-e1ab4fa3eaee